# Right way to use transactional and request-handler-advice-chain in a JPAOutboundGateway

Tags: spring-integration

I've got for a JPA Outbound-channel-adapter both transactional and request-handler-advice-chain. In the advice-chain I try to log the Exception, when it happens.
It iss not logged, but I know that it actually happend since the Message was sent to failover clickDbFailoverChannel . What can be a problem with it? Is it a bug in Spring Integration?

```
<int:channel id="clickDbWithFailoverChannelSite-1">
     <int:dispatcher load-balancer="none" task-executor="clickDbSiteRouterExecutor"/>
</int:channel>
<int:bridge input-channel="clickDbWithFailoverChannelSite-1"
     output-channel="jpaOutboundChannelSite-1" order="1" send-timeout="100" />
<int:bridge input-channel="clickDbWithFailoverChannelSite-1"
     output-channel="clickDbFailoverChannel" order="2" />
<int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter id="jpaOutboundChannelSite-1"
     persist-mode="PERSIST" flush-size="100" entity-manager-factory="emfSite-1">
    <int-jpa:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManagerSite-1" />
    <int-jpa:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="failureChannel" ref="clickDbFailureLogger"/>
            <property name="onFailureExpression" value="#exception"/>
        </bean>
    </int-jpa:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-jpa:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Sorry, not enough info. Some StackTrace to see where SI isn't right. Some ponters where it doesn't work correctly. How it should work and etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I can guess where is your issue. The real exception to rollback the transaction is caused before an internal logic, where `<request-handler-advice-chain>` does the stuff. That's why your `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` doesn't get a failure message.

To workaround your rollback issue, you should replace `<int-jpa:transactional>` with `<tx:advice>` within `<int-jpa:request-handler-advice-chain>`.

You should understand here that `<int-jpa:transactional>` is for entire `MessageHandler.handleMessage`, but `<int-jpa:request-handler-advice-chain>` is just for its part - `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage`.

**UPDATE**

TX Advice should be like this:

```
 <tx:advice transaction-manager="transactionManagerSite-1"/>
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Comment: Good. Let me check it from test-case

Comment: Updated an answer. Sorry

Comment: Thanks, there's no more `TransactionRequiredException`, but unfortunatelly I don't get as before Exception from RequestHandler in logs, when I i.e turn off the database. I expect something like "Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!". So actually it looks now like in original post. Only hibernate exception get cought (i.e field length validation and so on), but it worked also in original version

Comment: Anyway the config look already quite ugly. Do you have in plans do something handier for the issue?

Comment: You can configue `<tx:advice>` and `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` as separete beans and use here just `<beans:ref bean="">`

Comment: sorry was my bad. I didn't use `checkoutTimeout` in c3p0 Connection Pool and when there was DB outage no exception from getConnection()  was thrown and as consequence there was nothing to intercept in `<int-jpa:request-handler-advice-chain>`. I'll update my original post with actual configuration. Thanks Агтём

Comment: Sorry: I missed something. Does it work now for you or not? Why didn't you accept the answer then? And I'm glad that you fixed an issue. It's really very difficult to determine the issue, if you aren't in the subject of the the project. Cheers